# Why doesn't jQuery seem to wait for animation to finish?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

What  i'm trying to do is:

1. Fade in a progress bar.
2. When the fade finishes, animate the progressbar to 100%.
3. When the progressbar is at 100%, fade out the preogress bar.
4. when the fade out is completed, reset progress bar.

I thought this code would provide the solution:

```
    $('#savebar').fadeIn('fast', function () {
        $('#savebar .bar').animate({width: '100%'}, "slow", function () {
            $('#savebar').fadeOut('fast', function () { 
                $('#savebar .bar').css({'width':'0%'});
            });
        });
    });
```

The problem seem to be that the animate complete function executes to early. Is this because the browser doesn't render the progress bar fast enough or am I missing something here?

Here's a jsfiddle that's illustrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/dub6P/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like the fadeOut happens too soon. Try adding a delay before the fadeOut. The animation looks pretty good that way IMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dub6P/7/

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('#savebar').fadeIn('fast', function () {
    $('#savebar .bar').animate({width: '100%'}, "slow", function () {
             $('#savebar').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast', function () { 
                 $('#savebar .bar').css({'width':'0%'});
             });
         });
     });    
 });
```

​

Comment: I agree that this works fine but isn't the idea of the complete function to execute when the animation is completely done? Is  this because animate doesn't wait for the browser to render each step?

Comment: The comment is right on the money. Although this answer 'works' well enough in this instance, it doesn't address the core issue which is the `complete` callback not waiting for the animation to complete.

Answer (score 3):

Slow down the fadeout function and it seems to work fine.

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    $('#savebar').fadeIn('fast', function () {
        $('#savebar .bar').animate({width: '100%'}, "slow", function () {
            $('#savebar').fadeOut(1500, function () {
                $('#savebar .bar').css({'width':'0%'});
            });
        });
    });    
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/dub6P/5/

Comment: Do you have an explanation on my comment on tommy's answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think making animate faster and fadeout slower will solve:

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
  $('#savebar').fadeIn('fast', function () {
     $('#savebar .bar').animate({width: '100%'}, 500, function () {// 500 ms used
         $('#savebar').fadeOut(1500, function () {                // 1500 ms used
             $('#savebar .bar').css({'width':'0%'});
         });
     });
  });    
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dub6P/10/